# ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, spring, httpclient, timeoutexception

Facing below exception while making multiple concurrent requests to an external API. But when I am trying to perform the same operation using any bulk load testing tool like Jmeter, the issue is not encountered.
Also, the issue is not encountered when making requests in a sequential manner.

```
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.getResult(BasicFuture.java:70)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:80)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:70)
    at com.paytm.oe.common.utils.HttpUtil.hit(HttpUtil.java:98)
    at com.paytm.oe.http.service.impl.HttpServiceImpl.hit(HttpServiceImpl.java:471)
    at com.paytm.oe.http.service.impl.HttpServiceImpl.post(HttpServiceImpl.java:164)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:375)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.processNextPendingRequest(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:355)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.release(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:319)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.releaseConnection(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:364)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.releaseConnection(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:245)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.responseCompleted(MainClientExec.java:387)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:172)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:437)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:327)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Also attaching the code snippet for reference.

```
    public static HttpResponse hit(CloseableHttpAsyncClient client, HttpRequestBase requestBase, HttpRequest request, boolean clearCookies) {
        HttpResponse response = null;
        requestBase.setHeaders(convertMapToHeaders(request.getHeaders()));
        response = new HttpResponse();
        HttpContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        if (clearCookies) {
            context.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, new BasicCookieStore());
        }
        long startTime = 0;
        int call = 0;
        while (call < 2) {
            HttpResponse resp = null;
            try {
                Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(requestBase, context, null);
                resp = future.get();
                long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                response.setHttpCode(resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                if (resp.getEntity() != null) {
                    response.setBody(EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity()));
                }
                response.setHeaders(convertHeadersToMap(resp.getAllHeaders()));
                call = 2;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                <Printing exception logs here.>
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```